# Getting trouble with a tag in Overpass Turbo since few days

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Since few days, I'm getting an error while requesting ways with the tag 'natural' using Overpass-Turbo.

Here's an example of my requests: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/fEL

[image]

When I execute the request, I'm getting an ajax error: 'Request rejected. (e.g. server not found, request blocked by browser addon, request redirected, internal server errors, etc.)'.

This kind of request used to work very well before. The same request on nodes or relations work, it's only happening with ways tagged 'natural' (and maybe other tags). The error is the same using the webapp Overpass-Turbo.eu or requesting other servers such as http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter, http://overpass.osm.rambler.ru/cgi/interpreter or http://api.openstreetmap.fr/oapi/interpreter.

I don't know if there are internal issues in Overpass servers or OpenStreetMap database, or if overpass language has been modified, so if somebody has any further information, I would be interested to know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by a recent regression, which has already been fixed. Please see [this post](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.openstreetmap.overpass/237) for details. Your query should be running fine by now.